# Obter FormCollection em Navegação de Página

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, navegação

Em um sistema ASP.NET C# MVC4 eu possuo algumas telas onde mostro alguns dados. Essas telas possuem Filtros e navegação (limite máximo de 10 dados por pagina). Gostaria de saber como posso gravar o FormCollection de algum modo para que ele passe na paginação. Um exemplo do meu controle:

```
public ActionResult Orcamentos(int? page)
{

}

public ActionResult Orcamentos(int? page, FormCollection form)
{

}
```

Dentro destes métodos eu já faço tudo certinho, funcionando corretamente e mostrando na View corretamente. Agora na View que está o problema, na navegação das paginas eu conseguir passar o Form para que ele entre no método com Form.

Na View, a parte da Paginação esta dessa maneira:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, (page) => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page, form = @ViewBag.filtro }), PagedListRenderOptions.Classic )
```

Então onde ta @Viewbag.filtro eu teria que dar um jeito de passar o FormCollection (Colequei a Viewbag só de exemplo, pois a mesma não consegue armazenar o form)

Comment: `page` normalmente vem de um `GET`. `FormCollection` normalmente vem de um `POST`. Qual o objetivo desta implementação?

Comment: Quando exibe os dados na View, e ele é paginado, quando clico em um número de página lá, por exemplo 3, eu mando page=3 e também preciso mandar o Form pois eu efetuei um Filtro. O código da paginação seria esse: (Sendo que onde coloquei Viewbag.Filtro eu teria que passar uma FormCollection
   @Html.PagedListPager(Model, (page) => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page, form = @ViewBag.filtro }), PagedListRenderOptions.Classic )

Comment: Está errado. Se você quer definir um filtro, ele tem que ser por `GET` também, e não usando `FormCollection`. Ou você usa parâmetros nomeados ou você usa `FormCollection`. Os dois juntos não dá. No seu lugar, eu usaria um *ViewModel* definindo não apenas o filtro, mas a página em questão.